# Bi-directional mirror between minIO and filesystem

Tags: rsync, minio, mirror

For some time now, I try to find a solution for a bi-directional mirroring between a minIO bucket (of folder in a bucket) and a file system folder (mostly needed for linux).
I am familiar with the minIO mirroring command (mc mirror), but it doesn't suffice my needs. The mc mirror is only for filesystem->minIO mirroring, while I need the other direction as well.

By the way, best for my needs if the mirror will support also file removal, in the manner that a removal from the minIO will delete the file in the filesystem even if the file was initially created the filesystem (and synced to the minIO).

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Asaf